# Does OCaml support explicit type application?

Tags: generics, ocaml

Many languages allow the type parameters of generic functions to be explicitly given.

As an example, if we have a function in Java or TypeScript with the following signature:

```java
void f<T>();
```

…and a type `MyType`, we can write `f<MyType>()` to call `f` with type parameter `T` explicitly given as `MyType`.

Does OCaml have this feature?

If the answer is no – is this because the type inference of OCaml is so strong that a situation in which type application would be useful can never arise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OCaml type inference is principal outside of five exceptions (GADTs, higher-rank polymorphism, higher-order labeled functions, recursive polymorphism, and type-directed disambiguation). This means that the type inferred by the typechecker is always the most generic possible type and adding type annotations to some OCaml program can only transform a well-typed program into an ill-typed one, the reverse direction is not possible. (Once again outside of the advanced subset mentioned earlier).

In particular, the typing of function application is principal and the type of `f x` can always be inferred.

Thus it is neither needed nor useful to provide an explicit type argument à la System F to functions when writing an application.

Answer (score 1):

OCaml does not have ad hoc polymorphism. That is, you can't have a function behave differently based on the type of the arguments it's given or is expected to return. Therefore, the example you give from Java/TypeScript would simply be unsound in OCaml.

Additionally, OCaml allows type annotations on any expressions. Therefore there's no need for a distinct syntax specifically for function application. To annotate the return type of function application you could either do `(f (): my_type)` or `let x: my_type = f () in ...`, for example.

Comment: A common example in Scala of where type application is preferred is to avoid excessively long type expressions, e.g. `Map.empty[String, Int]` is preferred over `(Map.empty: Map[String, Int]` or `val map: Map[String, Int] = Map.empty`. This is commonly needed in Scala to assist the compiler with type checking as type inference is not as powerful as in OCaml. (It is also needed for implicit resolution which synthesises terms from types.) I take it from your answer that this scenario is so rare in OCaml that it does not warrant having type application as a feature.

Comment: Indeed. In my experience, type annotations on expressions (as opposed to top level definitions) are usually only needed to bring record fields into scope.